# Can I use any fibre channel card with IBM server or there is a special type?

Tags: pci-express

I have [this server](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpapers/pdfs/redp4362.pdf) and a disk array with fibre hard drives.

I want to know whether I can use any fibre card with IBM server or there is a special card which I can use

Currently I have [this card](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/QLOGIC-ISP2312-PCIX-133-DUAL-2GB-FIBRE-CHANNEL-CONTROLLER-CARD-FOR-HP-PROLIANT-/231099171089?pt=AU_Server_Accessories_Parts&hash=item35ce958111&_uhb=1). The speed is 2Gbs. Will that be enough for my local home lab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PCI-X (which the card is) isn't PCI-E. The server has PCIe slots, the card is PCI-X. You ought to be able to use any pci-e 8x card (or pcie 4x or 1x) with totally no issues.

As for speed, you'd know what you need, I'm perfectly happy with common gig-e myself.

Comment: thanks for that, what type of cable is used to connect them

Comment: Fiber channel? No clue. There's apparently different formats